# How can I select only rows that contain single digit floats?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

I have a dataframe containing mined comments (and responses) that look like this:

```
Comment_ID | COMMENT
1.0          foo
1.1          re:foo
1.2          re:foo
2.0          foo
```

The comment ID indicates whether a comment is toplevel or a response via the number. Even numbers are always top level comments (in this example 1.0 and 2.0) . I now want to extract only top level comments from my dataframe. How can I do this?

One solution I came up with was this

```
df = df[df['Comment_ID'] == 1.0]
```

but that only yields me one row. I need something like this (that works)

```
df = df[df['Comment_ID'] == 1.0:300.0]
```

Comment: `df[df['Comment_ID'].between(1,300)]`

Comment: Do you mean even numbers or whole numbers? Because only 2 is an even number, but 1 and 2 are whole numbers.

Comment: and maybe a good question is, if whole numbers, what is whole number, only 1.0 or even 1.0000038 for example? on one decimal both are same

Comment: Yeah I got that wrong, I meant whole numbers. The numbers are always whole in the sense "1.0", "45.0", "1845.0". The answer provided by mCoding did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is some operation you want to do to a column that is custom, you can always use `.apply`. E.g.

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Comment_ID':[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0], 'COMMENT':['foo','re:foo','re:foo','foo']})
    print(df)
    mask = df['Comment_ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x).partition('.')[2]) == '0'
    print(df[mask])
```

prints

```
   Comment_ID COMMENT
0         1.0     foo
1         1.1  re:foo
2         1.2  re:foo
3         2.0     foo
   Comment_ID COMMENT
0         1.0     foo
3         2.0     foo
```

I'm assuming here that all your data are of the form `number.digit` as in your example. If there can be multiple digits you would have to do something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @mCoding answer you could check whether your value is a whole number by other means e.g. described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number). One good example adapted from your question is:

```
df[df["Comment_ID"] % 1 == 0]
```