# How can i stop my python program from crashing

Tags: python, loops, factorial, floating

I wrote a program to calculate the factorial of a number all work perfectly but crashes when for test I enter a float number. 
My goal is for a floating number to be accepted but not calculated. As the program will accept but return something like "Bad entry, only integers are accepted."
I have tried multiple statement but it only work for the number I put in the statement. So I thought maybe something should be built, maybe by naming some floats and doing some sort of subtraction. But I get lost.
here is the program I have so far without the floating statement included:

```
    def main():
# take input from the user
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        factorial = 1
        if num > 100:
            print("Bad entry. It should be an integer less than or equal to 100!")
            print("Please try again: ")
        elif num == 0:
            print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
        elif num < 0:
            print("Bad entry. It should be an integer superior than or equal to 0!")
            print("Please try again: ")  
        else:
            for i in range(1,num + 1):
                factorial = factorial*i
            print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)

main()
```

Comment: Fix identation please

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float) on how to check if the number entered is integral.

Comment: Please include what you've tried to solve the floating point issue, and how it "crashes". Do you get an uncaught exception?

Comment: Look up `try/except`. You should be able to try the loop and send a message if it fails.

Comment: I might sound silly, but one cannot calculate factorial of float, can he? So, there's no reason to put try/excepts etc

Comment: You indented it badly. Again.

Comment: try/except is a good way to go on this. Alternatively, add another elif statement    elif num != int(num):

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def main():
    # take input from the user
    num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    if (num%1 != 0):
        print("Bad entry, only integers are accepted.")
        return 

    num = int(num)
    factorial = 1
    if num > 100:
        print("Bad entry. It should be an integer less than or equal to 100!")
        print("Please try again: ")
    elif num == 0:
        print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
    elif num < 0:
        print("Bad entry. It should be an integer superior than or equal to 0!")
        print("Please try again: ")  
    else:
        for i in range(1,num + 1):
            factorial = factorial*i
        print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)

main()
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation? Bare code blocks are bad.

Comment: The module operator '%' will return the remainder of the operation. So, 9%1 is 0 while 9.1%1 is .1. Once we have determined if its float you can convert it to an int.

Comment: Seems unnecessary. You should just try to convert to `int` and catch the `ValueError` if it fails. The only case you're saving yourself here is if the user gives you a float it will trigger a DIFFERENT error message than the bare traceback if they give you a non-number.

Comment: If you convert a float to an int it wont fail. It will truncate the number.

Comment: I suggest either A) convert to float then to int and use the resulting integer regardless of what the user entered, or B) do not convert to float, because `int("6.2")` DOES fail.

Comment: How would you put this in a while loop? @DanielRasmuson

Comment: 'while: main()' you could also have main return if it should continue. 'while main(): pass'

Answer (score 3):

You should use a try/catch block, since `int('3.2')` (or any other float string) will raise an error. For example:

```
try: num = int(input('Enter a number...'))
except ValueError:
   print 'We only accept integers.'
   return
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have suggested, you should use a `try/except` block. However if you want to accept user input like `"6.12"` and just calculate from the integer part, you should do:

```
user_in = "6.12" # or whatever the result from the input(...) call is
user_in = int(float(user_in)) # 6
```

`int` cannot operate on a string that's not integer-like, but it CAN operate on a floating point number. Calling `float` on the string will give you a floating point number, and calling `int` on that floating point number will return the integer part.