# Python Floating and Integer Numbers

Tags: python, types, numbers, integer, floating

I want check a type of a number in python, for example

```
x=4
y=2
type(x/y) == type(int)
--> False
```

it has to be True but what python makes is, it takes `4/2` as `2.0`.

`2.0` is a floating number, how can I make `2.0` to `2` but at the same time I don't want to make `2.5` to `2` for example :

```
x=5
y=2
type(x/y) == type(int)
--> False
```

This is what I want. In conclusion I need something that can understand if a number is int or a floating number after a division operation. Can you help me please

Comment: I think you want what is explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float

Comment: What's preventing you from writing a function that does just that?

Comment: but your problem here is that `type(int)` returns `<type 'type'>` not `<type 'int'>`

Comment: Having the result's type depend on the value is usually a bad idea. If you want to perform a divisibility test, there's a much better way to do that: `x % y == 0` if x is divisible by y.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `/` is going to be a float.  You can define your own function that wraps `/`

```
import math
def my_div(a, b):
    x = a/b
    if math.floor(x) == x:
        return int(x)
    return x
```

Comment: `return a//b if a//b == a/b else a/b` is equivalent

Comment: @TemporalWolf and probably unreadable for someone who doesn't grok the difference between a float and an int

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, `x/y` will always be of type `float`, so forget about `type`

If you only have int numbers as input you could just use modulo:

```
x%y == 0
```

yields `True` if the result is integer, `False` otherwise