# Can't check whether a number is integer or not

Tags: python

I have just started in Python.

Is there a way to check whether a particular number is integer or not.
e.g. `x=12.33`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: A lot of the answers are answering the question of how to check whether a number is an integer. They are ignoring that the variable x in your example is a float.There are two number types in Python: Integer and Float. In your example, 12.33 is a float. So all of the answers so far will return `False` since 12.33 is not an integer. Integer is a whole number such as `12`. If you already knew that, great! Regardless: welcome to Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number is int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float)

Comment: The answer selected is actually the wrong answer to this question. and the question itself is a duplicate.

Comment: We can't know if it's the wrong answer as the question is missing alot of information and shouldn't have (7!!!) answers

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I am sorry.. as am just a beginner to stack overflow. I was not knowing like how to ask a question and all. That selected answer worked for me so just accepted it.

Comment: Have a look in [ask] and maybe take the [tour]. I think the information your question is missing is what types are your inputs. Can you assure it's a float and want to check if it's a whole number? Can it be a string, int etc. This is relevant information

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you @Tomerikoo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `is_integer()` method:

```py
x.is_integer()
```

Comment: This assumes that `x` is a float to begin with... What if it's a string? What if it's already an int?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in python to solve this.

If you want to confirm the datatype then do then the recommended way is -

```
x = 12.33

isinstance(x, int)
#False

isinstance(x, float)
#True
```

The above approach is agnostic to the type of object x is to begin with.

You can also try the following ways -

```
x = 12.33

type(x) == int
#False

type(x) == float
#True

## This approach is not recommended as the is_integer method is available only for float type objects
x.is_integer()
#False
```

**If the variable is originally a string**, but you still wanna check if the element is potentially a numeric type then -

```
x = '12.33' 

x.isnumeric()
#False

x.isdigit()
#False

x.isdecimal()
#True
```

Answer (score 0):

`if type(x) == int`. `type(variable)` returns type of object. You just compare it with what you want

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is already a number (float), you can use [float.is_integer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)

```
>>> i = 4.0
>>> i.is_integer()
True

>>> i = 4.1
>>> i.is_integer()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type(var)` to check the data type.

```
x = 12.33

if type(x) == int:
    print("Integer")
elif type(x) == float:
    print("Float")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `type(<variable>)` function to determine the data type of it (Use if case for this). It will help!

Answer (score 0):

As some answers have suggested you can check the type of the variable, for instance:

```
x = 2
type(x) == int
```

however, if you want to check if the number is an integer even if it's stored as a float you could cast it to a float and compare it with itself.
i.e.

```
x = 2.000
int(x) == x
# True

y = 1.2043
int(y) == y
# False
```

If it is not an integer value the typecasting will truncate the number to just the integer part and it will no longer be equal.
It's worth noting this may not work for very large integers due to floating-point errors.