# writing python functions incorporating if and absolute

Tags: python, types

My python function when called skips the `if` statement I have given as the condition and directly executes the `else` statement. I would like to know why I am running into this error. My code seeks to verify `if` by calling an argument of an `int` or `float` type, I can get an absolute value.

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if type(a) == type(int) or type(a)== type(float)
        return abs(a)
    print(a)
    else:
        print('not possible')
```

Comment: you seem to have a few syntax errors there too

Comment: Functions shouldn't print anything on error. They should raise so it can be handled programmatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number is int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float)

Comment: the shortest code to check for this is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69145551/14531062) answer (I am not the OP of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would rather need to check if `a` is an instance of either a float or an integer.

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if isinstance(a, float) or isinstance(a, int):
        return abs(a)
    else:
        print('not possible')
```

Comment: This is the same as [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69145560/9857631) answer.

Comment: @not_speshal not exactly exactly, but I agree, you were first too

Comment: i see, it was 15 seconds after. Is it the right policy to delete your own answer when you see someone else said the same seconds ago?

Comment: No need to delete. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers). Just letting you know it's a duplicate answer.

Comment: @ph140 deleting an your answer is not a policy, it depends on either if it is forcefully deleted/removed by voting or moderator or if you remove it voluntarily

Comment: ok, just wondered if I should delete it, since you pointed out it was the same

Answer (score 2):

This should be

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if isinstance(a, (int, float))
        return abs(a)
    # having a print statement here breaks the if else flow
    else:
        print('not possible')
```

Comment: it is still incorrect, `isinstance` take only two arguments

Comment: learned something new today (argument as tuple for `isinstance` function), this is honestly the best answer so far

Comment: This aready exists with more information in [an answer with 119 upvotes in a thread with 588k views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35487663/6243352). Can we not mark it as a dupe?

Answer (score 1):

`type(int)` returns a `<class 'type'>`. You probably meant to check if the `type(a)` is an `int` or a `float`, not a `type(int)` or `type(float)`. Additioanlly, note that the `print(a)` statement is illegal. If you really need it, indent it under the `if` and put it **before** the `return` statement.

```py
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if type(a) == int or type(a) == float
        return abs(a)
    else:
        print('not possible')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use `isinstance` like so:

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if isinstance(a, int) or isinstance(a, float):
        return abs(a)
    else:
        print('not possible')
```

Comment: even better to use like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69145551/14531062) answer (TIL that you can pass tuple to `isinstance()` function)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the python community!
Your checks are not quite right, here you go -

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
  if type(a) == int or type(a)== float:
    return abs(a)
  else:
    print('not possible')
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside your syntax errors possible due to the copy paste, you need to check if the type of a is an `int` (float) not a `type(int)` (`type float`).

In python also types have a type: the type "type".

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>

>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

so your check should be:

```
if type(a) is int or type(a) is float:
    ...
```

Edit: In your comment you said it didn't work, so I put a snippet with the complete code so you can see it works and compare it to yours to see where you did different.

```
In [2]: def dist_frm_zero(a):
   ...:     if type(a) is int or type(a) is  float:
   ...:         return abs(a)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print('not possible')
   ...:

In [3]: dist_frm_zero(10)
Out[3]: 10

In [4]: dist_frm_zero(-0.432)
Out[4]: 0.432

In [5]: dist_frm_zero("Ciao")
not possible
```

Another two things about your question.

1. Fix the position of your `print` statement. In that position is a syntax error, and if intended to be in the `if`, it would still be after a return so it'll never be executed.
2. A function that sometimes returns a number, sometimes returns `None` and prints a statement it's not the best from many points of view. A better solution would be to `assert` the input is correct or to raise a `TypeError` exception. Another solution would be to omit the checks and let the exception be thrown directly by the `abs` function which when an input with the wrong type is passed throws the following:

```
>>> abs("ciao")
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

So two better solutions would be:

```
def dist_frm_zero(a):
    return abs(a)


def dist_frm_zero(a):
    if type(a) not in [int, float]:
     raise TypeError("a must be an int or a float")
    return abs(a)
```

Comment: Hi, tried this too but it didn't work. not sure why