# Problems with my if conditions and floats

Tags: python

I need to find if a number is a float or an integer in an `if condition` and I'm having trouble doing so in Python. Will I need to use the `is_integer()` method and if so how?

Comment: Use *isinstance()*

Comment: Do you mean is the variable of type `int` or `float`, or does the float (approximately) equal an integer value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number is int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: @Cdr Is there any code you are trying with?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code like this:

```py
value = 1.5

if type(value) == float:
    print("it is float")
```

Comment: You can also use `is`. `if type(value) is float :`

Comment: Yes, You are right

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance` is a built in method for this purpose.

```
my_var = 5.5    # float

if isinstance(my_var, float):
   print(f'{my_var} is a float')
elif isinstance(my_var, int):
   print(f'{my_var} is an integer')
```