# How to make a simple Python branch which stops if requirements found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is:

```
varA = 5
varB = 'dog'
if type(varB) == 'string':
    print("string involved")
elif type(varA) == 'string':
    print("string involved")
else:
    if varA > varB:
        print("bigger")
    elif varA == varB:
        print("equal")
    elif varA < varB:
        print("smaller")
```

I get error on line 8. I want the code not to react on line 7 else statement, if it has already met the requirements for if(line3) or elif(line5)!

Also, how to use 'or' method so it joins toget if(line3) and elif(line5) statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `isinstance` to check for `type`:

```
varA = 5
varB = 'dog'
if isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str):
    print("string involved")
else:
    if varA > varB:
        print("bigger")
    elif varA == varB:
        print("equal")
    else:
        print("smaller")
```

Here you are checking that the variables are of the `str` type, and if either one of them is, you know a string is involved and will therefore not execute the `else` code.

The `or` can be done by essentially combining the two conditions into one line, as in the example. Here it isn't a big issue, another way you can simulate an `or` statement is to use `any`, which checks if any of the conditions are `True` and executes if so:

```
if any((isinstance(varA, str), isinstance(varB, str))):
    # Code...
```

This comes in handy when you have a large data structure and need to do a similar `or` comparison. The `and` equivalent is `all`, which has the same syntax, just using `all` instead of `any`:

```
if all((isinstance(varA, str), isinstance(varB, str))):
    # This code will evaluate if all values are strings
```

And if you have a bunch of checks and get tired of typing `isinstance`, you can bundle that part a bit further by using a `generator` in combination with `any` or `all`:

```
if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in (varA, varB)):
    # Code
```

Comment: The last condition is not necessary. It should just be `else`.

Comment: @John Yeah, I was just copying the original code, but good point - I'll remove :)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that `type()` returns a type object, not a string, so you are comparing `type(varB) = <type 'str'>` with the actual string `string`, and they are not the same.

Then you compare `5` and a string, which throws an error because there is no way to compare them.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python) explains in detail a bunch of different ways to check types.