# User defined type checking in python: "type(A()) is A" returns false

Tags: python, types

From this post - [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python), I could use this code to check object o is string type.

```
o = "str"; print type(o) is str --> True
```

However, with user defined type, `type(a) is A` doesn't seem to work.

```
class A:
    def hello(self):
        print "A.hello"
a = A()

print type(a) is A # --> False
print type(a) == A # --> False
```

Why is this? How can I get the correct type checking for user defined type?
I use python 2.7 on Mac OS X.

PS: This is a question out of curiosity, as I got this example from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B74AIPU) to get true as a result, but I got  false. I understand that Duck typing is a preferred way in python. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/154156/260127)

### ADDED

rodrigo's answer works for me. Using 'isinstance' doesn't give me an exact type, it just tests if an object is an instance of a class or a subclass.

```
class C(A):
    def hello(self):
        print "C.hello"

a = A()
c = C()

print isinstance(a, A) --> True
print isinstance(c, A) --> True
print isinstance(a, C) --> False
print isinstance(c, C) --> True
print "----"
print type(a) == A --> True
print type(c) == A --> False
```

### ADDED 2

jdurango's answer (`a.__class__ is A`) gave me pretty interesting Java equivalent.

```
a.getClass() == A.class <--> a.__class__ == A (a.__class__ is A)
a isinstance A <--> isinstance(a, A)
c isinstance A <--> isinstance(c, A)
```

I don't know which copied which.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the new-style classes:

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

That is, derive it from `object`.

The problem is that object of old-style are implemented as if all of them were of type `instance`.

Deriving directly or indirectly from `object` will solve this issue. Or moving to Python3, where there is no more old-style classes.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `isinstance(instance, class)`?

```
>>> class A:
...     def hello(self):
...        print "A.hello"
... 
>>> type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
>>> isinstance(a, A)
True
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
print a.__class__ is A
True
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are defining `a` like `a = A()` then `a` is an instance of the class `A`. If you are just doing `a = A`, then the name `a` points to the class object.

You probably want an instance of `A` and can then test that with

```
>>> a = A()
>>> isinstance(a, A)
True
```

New style classes will test True to `type(A()) == A` though.