# raise TypeError exception for incorrect input value in a class

Tags: python, class, exception

I am trying to write a `class` and I want that if the initial input values for the class don't obey specific types, it would raise an exception. For instance I would use `except TypeError` to return an error. I don't know how it should be done though. My first attempt to write the `class` is as following:

```
class calibration(object):
      def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, calibration_info, interpolations=2):
          try:
            self.inputs=inputs
          except TypeError

          self.outputs=outputs
          self.cal_info=calibration_info
          self.interpol=interpolations
```

I would like that if `inputs` value is not a string then it raises an error message. I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python.

Comment: And if you see the wrong type, you may want to call `raise TypeError` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a bit different between 2.x and 3.x, but use isinstance to figure out type and then raise the exception if you are not satisfied.

```
class calibration(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, calibration_info, interpolations=2):
        if not isinstance(inputs, basestring):
            raise TypeError("input must be a string")
```

Python2 differentiates between ascii and unicode strings - "basestring" convers them both. In python3, there are only unicode strings and you use 'str' instead.

Comment: I use `python 2.7`, so `basestring` treats them the same,right?

Comment: @Dalek - yes basestring will match both of them.

Comment: what about `six.string_types`, what is its difference with `basestring`?

Comment: I hadn't heard of `six` until now. Its in my python2 and resolves to a tuple with one item `(<type 'basestring'>,)` So, you could use it instead. But its not in my python3 distribution, which makes it kinda useless for 2 + 3 conformant code IMHO. In the end, I just don't know enough about six to say if its helpful.