# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') when I scale my data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to normalize my data like this :

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
trainX=scaler.fit_transform(X_data_train)
```

and I get this error :

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

`X_data_train` is a pandas DataFrame of size `(95538, 550)`. What is really odd is that when I write

```
print (X_data_train.min().min())
```

it gives -5482.4473 and similarly for the max, I get 28738212.0, which does not seem for me to be extra-high values...

Moreover, based on the command given by the 54+ voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for), I did check I have no `NaN` or `Infinity` for sure. Moreover, I don't have blanks in my `csv`or things like that, as I checked the dimensions

So, where is the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check `NaN`s and `inf`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,np.inf],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[np.nan,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (df)
          B  C    D  E
0  4.000000  7  NaN  5
1  5.000000  8  3.0  3
2  4.000000  9  5.0  6
3  5.000000  4  7.0  9
4  5.000000  2  1.0  2
5       inf  3  0.0  4

nan = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
print (nan)
     B  C   D  E
0  4.0  7 NaN  5

inf = df[df.eq(np.inf).any(axis=1)]
print (inf)
     B  C    D  E
5  inf  3  0.0  4
```

If want find all index with at least one `NaN`s in rows:

```
print (df.index[np.isnan(df).any(axis=1)])
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

And columns:

```
print (df.columns[np.isnan(df).any()])
Index(['D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Why do I get a `nan` array clearly non empty when applying your method but I get `True` when doing `print (np.any(np.isnan(df)))` ?

Comment: `nan = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]` ?

Comment: Hmmm, what return `print (df[np.isnan(df).any(axis=1)])` ? It seems some NaNs ?

Comment: Yes, I get a quite huge dataframe. However, why does `np.any(np.isnan(df)` gives True ? I am confused about this...

Comment: @MysteryGuy - because `np.any` with no argument return `True` if at least one `NaN` in `df`. So problem is `NaN`s.

Comment: @jezrael, how `df.drop` differs from `df.pop`

Comment: @pyd - `pop` extract column from `df` and drop delete it. Extracting means after  `a = df.pop('col')`  in `a` is Series `col` and in `df` is no column `col`.

Comment: @MysteryGuy - Sure, check now.