# sklearn: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While trying to run this

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values ="NaN", strategy = "mean")
imputer = SimpleImputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = SimpleImputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

I am getting an error

> TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

But I already provided x, right?
What is the solution for this?

Comment: what is the value of X?

Comment: the "fit" method only accepts numpy arrays as input. so make sure that it is of the right type

Comment: `dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`
`X = dataset.iloc[:,: -1].values`

Comment: @gireesh4manu i provided this for x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Scikit-learn module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html), the correct syntax should be:

`imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])`

instead of:

`imputer = SimpleImputer.fit(X[:,1:3])`

Comment: it worked but raised another exception.  Actually, I am trying to replace the "NaN" value with the mean of other observation

Comment: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Comment: Does X contain NaN or inf values?

Comment: yes,it contain NaN values and that's what i am trying to replace with mean of other observation @sheldon

Comment: Check out this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for

Answer (score 3):

The completely worked code looks like:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = "mean")
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

Please pay attention to:

```
missing_values = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code :

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
# PAY ATTENTION: to NaN as np.nan
imputer = SimpleImputer(**missing_values ="NaN"**, strategy = "mean")
imputer = SimpleImputer.fit(X[:,1:3])
# PAY ATTENTION: instead of "SimpleImputer.transform" use "imputer.transform"
X[:,1:3] = **SimpleImputer**.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

Correct Code :

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer  
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean',fill_value=None, verbose=0, copy=True)  
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])  
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```