# I get a ValueError in sklearn because of NaN/inf or dtype. Ive checked the data, cant find any errors

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to pass some data to sklearn, but i only get the error "contains NaN/inf or wrong dtype".

The data i got is mostly weather data i got from csv-files and merged in pandas.

I've checked for NaN and inf-values and wrong datatypes.

```
np.isfinite(X_train).all()
True

np.any(np.isnan(X_train))
False

X_train.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I also tried to use just some columns and rows to narrow it down, but even with just any two columns and some rows i get the same error.

I've converted the pandas dataframe to an numpy before passing it to sklearn, ive tried re-indexing it. I've written it to a csv-file and inspected it for weird entrys. All solutions i could find didn't work for me.

The code i'm trying to use is this:

```
X = climate.drop(columns=['e_bins'])
y = climate.e_bins
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=33)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

I'm working on this problem for a while now, with now success. Any help or ideas appreciated! Thanks!

This is the whole error i receive:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-14fc949c5576> in <module>
     17 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
     18 knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
---> 19 knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
     20 #y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
     21 #accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    890         """
    891         if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree)):
--> 892             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
    893 
    894         if y.ndim == 1 or y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
--> 722                         dtype=None)
    723     else:
    724         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

Comment: can you upload the data?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error while doing feature importance and I found the cols which have infinite values using below. Please check if they may help

```
# getting the cols which have infinite values 
col_name = train_df.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(train_df).any()]
print(col_name)
```