# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') on Django project

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn, python-3.6, face-recognition

I tried https://github.com/samarth-p/Face_recognition this repo. I can't use identify feature

Work on Ubuntu 18.04 with Jatson Nano. Use Python3 and i tried virtualenv

```
Internal Server Error: /identify/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py                                             ", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", li                                             ne 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", li                                             ne 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/spoofer/kurulum/app/views.py", line 180, in identify
    identify_faces(video_capture)
  File "/home/spoofer/kurulum/app/views.py", line 94, in identify_faces
    predictions = predict(rgb_frame, model_path="app/facerec/models/trained_mode                                             l.clf")
  File "/home/spoofer/kurulum/app/views.py", line 66, in predict
    closest_distances = knn_clf.kneighbors(faces_encodings, n_neighbors=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line                                              402, in kneighbors
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", lin                                             e 542, in check_array
    allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", lin                                             e 56, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: Where is the code that caused this error?

Comment: https://github.com/samarth-p/Face_recognition/blob/master/app/facerec/identify_faces.py

Comment: what I meant was: what code did *you* run that caused this error? Or when did this error occur? runtime or when you imported the package?

Comment: in django app, i tried push the identify button and i saw this error in terminal. identify button link to this code.
Screen photos
https://ibb.co/CnKbs8R
https://ibb.co/PrqJ37p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

Comment: here are a lot of answers to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for