# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') in linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I tried resetting index but it didn't helped.

Python version 3.7

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
housing = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
X = housing.iloc[:, housing.columns !='median_house_value'].values
y = housing.iloc[:, 9].values
print(X[0])


housing.head()


from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 8] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 8])


print(X[0])


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
#testing/predicting using test set
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

i am getting error at regressor.fit() method.

[image: error image]

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for

Comment: clean your data with `fillna()` etc.   Always the same with models-need to meet content requirements as well as shape. data quality is everything :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found an answer that there were some missing data, empty cells more accurate to say. Here is the Solution if you encounter such an error.

1. **Check for empty cells**.

   Run `dataframename.isnull().sum()` (replace ***dataframename*** with ***your dataframe name*** method to your dataframe.

   This will show you in which columns have empty or NaN cells.
2. **Remove Empty Cells**

   Run `dataframename = dataframename.dropna()` to remove empty cells.

   Check this site for more filters https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html
3. **Confirm it**

   Run `dataframename.isnull().sum()` to check whether there are any empty cells.

That's it Done!! Now Continue with your remaining part of the program.