# ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). With normal values

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pycharm, data-science

I ran a test, but there was an error. The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alina/PycharmProjects/quick_trade/quick_trade/quick_trade/trading_sys.py", line 1892, in <module>
    trader.backtest(commission=0.075, show=False, plot=False)
  File "/Users/alina/PycharmProjects/quick_trade/quick_trade/quick_trade/trading_sys.py", line 1455, in backtest
    MinMaxScaler(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 690, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 336, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 369, in partial_fit
    X = self._validate_data(X, reset=first_pass,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 420, in _validate_data
    X = check_array(X, **check_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 73, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 645, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 97, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the error occurs at this piece of code

```
profits = []
    from itertools import chain
    for ticker in chain.from_iterable([
         ...
         [['BCH-USD', '1d', 'max'], ['BCH-USD', '1m', '5d'], ['BCH-USD', '1d', '3y']],
         ...
    ]):
        print(ticker)
        TICKER = ticker[0]
        interval = ticker[1]
        df = yf.download(TICKER, interval=interval, period=ticker[2])
        trader = PatternFinder(df=df, interval=interval, ticker=TICKER)
        trader.set_client(TradingClient)
        trader.set_pyplot()
        trader.load_model('./model_regression')
        trader.prepare_scaler(dataframe=trader.df, regression_net=True)
        trader.strategy_regression_model()
        trader.log_deposit()
        trader.backtest(commission=0.075, show=False, plot=False)
        profits.append((trader.year_profit, ticker))
    print(profits)
```

and

```
self.backtest_out_no_drop = self.backtest_out
        self.backtest_out = self.backtest_out.dropna()
        if log_profit_calc:
            _log = np.log
        else:
            _log = nothing
        self.lin_calc = self.linear_(
            MinMaxScaler(
                feature_range=(
                    min(self.money_list),
                    max(self.money_list)
                )
            ).fit_transform(
                np.array([_log(deposit_df['deposit Close'].values)]).T
            ).T[0])
        lin_calc_df = pd.DataFrame(self.lin_calc)
```

> min(self.money_list),
> max(self.money_list)
> is
> -2574.343034345313, 16269.23923437693

full code here: https://github.com/VladKochetov007/quick_trade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov sorry, but no