# Python Replacing missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to replace missing values in a specific column in a dataframe, but having some issues.
Have tried:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
fill_0_with_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean')
X_train['Age'] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train['Age'])
```

and

```
X_train[:,15] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train[:,15])
```

and

```
X_train[:,15:16] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train[:,15:16])
```

and

```
X_train['Age'] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train['Age'].values)
```

and

```
X_train[:,15:16] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train[:,15:16].values)
```

But I keep getting errors around
**ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').** or **IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices**

I have zero and missing (NaN) values in my data. Can the imputer only do one of the two? How do I go about doing this?
I have also tried casting my age column as an integer

```
X_train['Age'] = X_train['Age'].as_type('int32')
```

But this just gives me other errors.

my data looks like (the Age column)

|  | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 31.0 |
| 1 | 79.0 |
| 2 | 53.0 |
| 3 | 40.0 |
| 4 | 55.0 |
|  | ... |
| 44872 | NaN |
| 44873 | NaN |
| 44874 | NaN |
| 44875 | NaN |
| 44876 | NaN |

Is it possible that numpy and pandas are getting mixed up? I used this to split my data into training and testing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dep_var = ['is_overdue']
features = model_data2.columns
features = features.drop(dep_var)

print(features)

X = model_data2[features].values
Y = model_data2[dep_var].values

split_test_size = 0.30

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=split_test_size, random_state=42)
```

I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for

Answer (score 0):

As you want to replace 0 by mean, you have to fill `NaN` by 0:

```
fill_0_with_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean')
X_train['Age'] = fill_0_with_mean.fit_transform(X_train['Age'].fillna(0))
```

Comment: Then I get this error: 
`
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
`