# Checking for type() and changing if str() or int()

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, sqlalchemy

EDITED for clarity:

I am trying to solve the problem of `category` being `None` which is causing the error: `TypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like`

I am trying to just do a check to see whether I have a string, int, or object when creating an instance of this object `category` in order to pass it through the ORM in my tables. I kept coming across an Error (shown above), so I want to create a check that lets objects pass if they are objects.

Code that I have been reworking, but does not do exactly what I am hoping it would do. Any help / explanation would be GREATLY appreciated!

Class here

```
class BaseAPI(object):
    def create_element(self, element_text, category): # OBJ
        new_element = Element(element_text, category)
        self.session.add(new_element)
        self.session.commit()
        print(element_text)


 class ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI):
    def create_element(self, element_text, category_name):
        category = category_name
        if type(category) == str:
            category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
        elif type(category) == int:
            print('Sorry integers not accepted')
        else:
            return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_element(element_text, category)
```

In a test.py file, I create both instances of element and category:

```
api = ConvenienceAPI()
    sa = api.create_category('Situation Awareness')
    api.create_element('gathering information', sa)

    api.create_category('Leadership')
    api.create_element('gathering information', 'Leadership')
```

*ADDED* TRACEBACK ERROR after running test.py:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 41, in test1
    sa3 = api.create_element('projecting and anticipating future state', sa)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/convenience.py", line 22, in create_element
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_element(element_text, category)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 192, in create_element
    new_element = Element(element_text, category)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 306, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 303, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/model/base.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.category = category
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 224, in __set__
    instance_dict(instance), value, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1022, in set
    lambda adapter, i: adapter.adapt_like_to_iterable(i))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1038, in _set_iterable
    new_values = list(adapter(new_collection, iterable))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1022, in <lambda>
    lambda adapter, i: adapter.adapt_like_to_iterable(i))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 636, in adapt_like_to_iterable
    given, wanted))
TypeError: Incompatible collection type: None is not list-like

-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
--start db Session--
Situation Awareness
(u'Leadership', 1)
```

Comment: What if `type(x) == unicode`?

Comment: `x = category`. did you mean `x=category_name` ?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist instead of string maybe it is better to do: isinstance(x, basestring)

Comment: @MosheRabaev the issue I am having is that when I create an instance of an element, if the object is not an object I get a Traceback Error indicating that Category is NONE. By testing and converting, I can avoid this error. I don't think I fully understand your comment.

Comment: ```category``` coming from where, would be good to define it somewhere?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that it's clearer you're trying to solve the problem of `x` (I think!) sometimes being `None`, so people will stop getting hung up on your apparently uninitialized `category` and the string test?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist edited. Thanks! I hope this is clearer.

Comment: @amarie Very much so. It would also help if you could add more of the traceback so we can figure out where exactly it is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

In the first test case of test.py:

```
sa = api.create_category('Situation Awareness')
api.create_element('gathering information', sa)
```

`sa` is equal to the return value of the function `api.create_category()`. I'm going to assume that this function has no defined return value, which would cause `sa` to be `None`. What you're really calling on the next line of that test is `api.create_element('gathering information', None)`, resulting in your unexpected type of 'None' being passed sqlalchemy when it expects something that is iterable.

### Simple Solutions

- Don't assign the results of `create_category()` to a variable because there aren't any, and instead use the API in the same way as the leadership example. Basically don't ever do anything similar to `sa = api.create_category('Situation Awareness')`
- Edit the `create_category()` function to return it's input category. For example, `create_category("Situation Awareness")` should return "Situation Awareness", instead of `None`.

### The root of the Problem

Type safety. You're making assumptions about the type of variables being passed around that aren't necessarily true. In particular, look at:

```
 class ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI):
    def create_element(self, element_text, category_name):
        category = category_name
        if type(category) == str:
            category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
        elif type(category) == int:
            print('Sorry integers not accepted')
        else:
            return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_element(element_text, category)
```

The assumption is that in the `else:` clause, `category` is some type of object. But as you can see, as soon as `category` isn't a str, an int, or an object, you immediately get errors. And that still leaves the question of what type of object is the BaseAPI expecting.
Possible Solution:

```
class ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI):
    def create_element(self, element_text, category_name):
        category = category_name

        # if category is None, then this will fail
        # and print out the type (since None evaluates to False).
        if category:
            if isinstance(category, basestring):
                category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
            # Is int and float the only numeric types that can happen?
            elif isinstance(category, int) or isinstance(float) : 
                print('Sorry integers not accepted')
            else:
                # Danger Zone!!
                return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_element(element_text, category)
        else:
            print('Sorry, category is type %s' % str(type(category)))
```

Note that we're checking `basestring` instead of just `str`. This is because `category` might be unicode, which is valid text, but it's not a `str`. Both `str` and `unicode` are subclasses of `basestring`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/152596/5249060 for more info on that.

Even if you take that fix, what happens in the danger zone if category is anything other than a `str` or an `int`? What happens if it's an object, but not the kind that BaseAPI is expecting? I'm going to stop this answer here, because there are several options available that would fix this issue.

To clarify some of my earlier edits and comments, one of the ways that you help this code out is by creating a default object for `category` if it isn't a `str`, `int`, or some kind of object instead of logging an error message. However, that really depends on whether or not there is an acceptable default given what you're working on.

Comment: Meaning the problem area is indeed in that default case. If you know that `category` should be an object, the jist of what I'm suggesting is to make a default value (object in this case) for `category`. Also, which of your two test cases is failing? I would ask in a comment on your question, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I am actually returning a value in my table: ```class Element(Base):
#code
    #category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.category_id'))
    category = relationship('CategoryElementLink', backref='elements')
    
    def __init__(self, element_text, category):
        self.element_text = element_text
        self.category = category
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Element(element_text='%s', category='%s')>" % (self.element_text, self.category)```

Comment: Your element class can return a value, but what about `api.create_category()`?

Comment: `api.create_category(..)` is just like `api.create_element(..)`  but the table returns  the category_name: `class Category(Base):   
    __tablename__ = 'categories'    
    category_id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True)
    category_name = Column(String(2000))
    def __init__(self, category_name):
        self.category_name = category_name  
    def __repr__(self): return "<Category(category_name='%s')>" % (self.category_name)`

Comment: ~the method to `create_category(self, category_name)` is just like `create_element` but without mention of an element (of course)

Comment: There's still some things I don't understand here. Example: if your **first step** of a function is renaming one of its arguments (`category = category_name`), why not just rename the argument in the function definition? Also, these type tests still are not right. `isinstance(x, basestring)` is vastly better than `type(x) == str`. Likewise I wonder if you also mean to exclude `floats` as well as `ints`. If that's the case what happens if someone passes `decimal.Decimal`? Finally, there is still no `is not None` test here.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Couple of clarifications about the code. `create_category(category_name)` is the function to define a category name in the table. In the `element`, it is NOT to redfine it, but to *call* it by name. I agree that `isinstance(x, basestring)` is the way to go and a need to cover floats should be included. I have that changed in my code. I *agree* a need to test/ ensure that `is not None` doesn't get passed.

Comment: @amarie I'm not sure I understand your objection to the first point, though. I'm saying if you have `def function(x, y, z)` and the first line of it is `a = z`, then that line should be removed and the function signature should be `def function(x, y, a)`. If the first step of your function body is to rename one of its arguments, then just change the function signature and name it what you want in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `is not None` test being referred to is inside of `ConvenienceAPI.create_element()` or not. I'll update my work-in-progress answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I just realized the issue you were referring to: 'renaming my argument' -- that is not what I am trying to do. Thank you for that catch! I am trying to check that argument `category_name` through the tests.

Comment: At this point, @amarie, you need to clarify what exactly your problem is that you want help with. Multiple edits have been suggested, and I'm not sure what you're trying to get out of us at this point.

Comment: these are good suggestions and I am implementing and reworking now.

Answer (score 1):

I know, as my downvotes on other answers have shown, that this is somewhat tangential to your question. Nonetheless, I think you are making a mistake with the way you are checking types (which you report having at least partially corrected). I will leave this program here for your consideration:

```
"""
Exploration of type testing in Python.
"""

def type_test(x):
    """
    Reject strings, numbers, and None. Other objects pass through.
    """
    if x is None:
        return 'Must pass an object: None given.'

    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        if isinstance(x, basestring):
            return 'String types are not accepted.'
        else:
            return x
    else:
        return 'Numeric types are not accepted.'


def bad_string_test(x):
    """
    Only testing for 'str' type lets unicode fall through.
    """
    if isinstance(x, str) or type(x) == str or type(x) is str:
        return 'Strings are not accepted.'

    return x


def bad_numeric_test(x):
    """
    Only testing for 'int' or even 'int' and 'float' fails
    for numeric types like decimal.Decimal
    """
    if isinstance(x, int) or type(x) == int or type(x) is int:
        return 'Integers are not accepted.'
    elif isinstance(x, float) or type(x) == float or type(x) is float:
        return 'Floats are not accepted.'

    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from decimal import Decimal
    print "bad_string_test('Hello') ->", bad_string_test('Hello')
    print "bad_string_test(u'Hello') ->", bad_string_test(u'Hello')
    print "type_test('Hello') ->", type_test('Hello')
    print "type_test(u'Hello') ->", type_test(u'Hello')
    print "bad_numeric_test(1) ->", bad_numeric_test(1)
    print "bad_numeric_test(1.0) ->", bad_numeric_test(1.0)
    print "bad_numeric_test(Decimal('1.0')) ->",\
            bad_numeric_test(Decimal('1.0'))
    print "type_test(1) ->", type_test(1)
    print "type_test(1.0) ->", type_test(1.0)
    print "type_test(Decimal('1.0')) ->", type_test(Decimal('1.0'))
    print "type_test(None) ->", type_test(None)
```

Output:

```
bad_string_test('Hello') -> Strings are not accepted.
bad_string_test(u'Hello') -> Hello
type_test('Hello') -> String types are not accepted.
type_test(u'Hello') -> String types are not accepted.
bad_numeric_test(1) -> Integers are not accepted.
bad_numeric_test(1.0) -> Floats are not accepted.
bad_numeric_test(Decimal('1.0')) -> 1.0
type_test(1) -> Numeric types are not accepted.
type_test(1.0) -> Numeric types are not accepted.
type_test(Decimal('1.0')) -> Numeric types are not accepted.
type_test(None) -> Must pass an object: None given.
```

Things to notice:

- Instead of trying to enumerate all numeric types, we simply try a cast to float, interpreting failure as the object being a "numeric type". This casts a wider net and will also pick up such things as `decimal.Decimal`, which I assume you also want to rule out.
- `type_test` contains an explicit `None` test. This is required since `float(None)` raises a `TypeError`, which you basically never want to catch.

Comment: This is great test method for checking all the tables/entities. It is explicit with None ... might be good to make it take *args to run against the tables. But I would allow strings and convert to object.