# Unorderable types: type() > int()

Tags: python, python-3.3

I get the error 'TypeError: unorderable types: type() > int()' and i am not sure how to fix it.

```
    print ("Hello user, and welcome to the game.")
    print ("As you are a new user you will need to register your details, you will be asked to enter your age, gender, \nemail address and player name.")

    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    max_age = (122)

    while type(age) != int and type(age) > max_age:
        print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
        age_attempt = input("Please enter your age: ")
        break

    gender = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ")
    while type(gender) != Male or Female:
        print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
        gender_attempt  = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ")
        break
```

Comment: in your code is so much wrong, `input` returns always strings,  `or` does not work as you think, literal strings must be in quotes, ...

Comment: Preparing an minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is useful for several reasons. One is that it would reduce the code you'll have to post, but also it will provide you with insights about the fault (and maybe figure it out yourself). The code would reduce to `type(whatever_you_input) > 122`, which is wrong because in python3 you can't compare a type object and a number (in python2 it is possible, but don't make much sense anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare a type with an integer here:

```
while type(age) != int and type(age) > max_age:
```

Remove the `type()` call from the `>` comparison:

```
while type(age) != int and age > max_age:
```

The `type(age) != int` call will always fail, because the `input()` function always returns objects of type `str` instead. You need to convert your input value to an integer first, perhaps using `try...except` to catch errors:

```
try:
    age = int(age)
except ValueError:
    # not a string that can be converted
```

See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for a canonical question and answer on that subject.

You make the same mistake with your other test:

```
while type(gender) != Male or Female:
```

You need to test `gender` against two different values, so use a membership test:

```
while gender not in {'Male', 'Female'}:
```

See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) why `gender != 'Male' or 'Female'` doesn't work.

Comment: This also is a probelm `while type(gender) != Male or Female:`

Comment: why? and can you help me fix it? @VigneshKalai

Answer (score 0):

**Small adding  to @martin's code**

**Process:**

1.Get user age input check whether they are int and lesser then max limit

2.Get Gender and check if they are either male or female if not prompt again else finish

**Code:**

```
print ("Hello user, and welcome to the game.\n")
print ("As you are a new user you will need to register your details, you will be asked to enter your age, gender, \nemail address and player name.\n")

max_age = 122

while True:  #Loops while break condition is meet .That is if no break is there it will become inifinite 
    try:
        age = int(input("\nPlease enter your age: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
        continue    
    if age<max_age:        
        break # exit loop when max age is high then input
    print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")  

gender = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ")

while gender.lower().strip() not in {"male","female"}:

    print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
    gender  = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ") # Note same variable is used here not different variable
```

**Notes:**

`type` is used find the type of the given argument .For more on type see this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

```
>>> i = 123
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(i) is int
True
>>> i = 123456789L
>>> type(i)
<type 'long'>
>>> type(i) is long
True
>>> i = 123.456
>>> type(i)
<type 'float'>
>>> type(i) is float
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example :

```
print ("Hello user, and welcome to the game.")
print ("As you are a new user you will need to register your details, you will be asked to enter your age, gender, \nemail address and player name.")

age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
max_age = 122

while age>max_age:
    print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
    age_attempt = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    break

gender = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ")
while type(gender) != Male or Female:
    print ("Sorry what you have entered is invalid. Please try again")
    gender_attempt  = input("Please enter your gender. Male/Female: ")
    break
```