# Check the type of the arguments in a function/method in Python

Tags: python, exception, types, arguments

In Python, I would like to check the type of the arguments passed to a function.

I wrote two implementations:

```
class FooFloat(float):
    pass

# Solution 1
def foo(foo_instance):
   if type(foo_instance) is FooFloat:
      raise TypeError, 'foo only accept FooFloat input'


# Solution 2
def foo(foo_instance):
   assert type(foo_instance) is FooFloat, 'foo only accept FooFloat input'
```

In my opinion the latter is easier to read and less boilerplate. However it will throw an `AssertionError` which is not the type of error I would like to raise.

Is there a better third solution in this case more common?

I was thinking about a decorator:

```
@argtype('foo_instance', FooFloat)
def foo(foo_instance):
   pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for Python Assert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944592/best-practice-for-python-assert)

Comment: There is a type hint feature in Python 3.5: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: @eph: But it doesn't do any checking.

Comment: @user2357112: Python encourages to check attr instead of type. But you can still do type checking with a decorator as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32844779/918120 or in mypy http://mypy-lang.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this idea and thinking of using it in future. I implement the third solution as following, please have a try.

```
def argtype(arg_name, arg_type):
    def wrap_func(func):
        def wrap_args(*args, **kwargs):
            if not isinstance(kwargs.get(arg_name), arg_type):
                raise TypeError, '%s\'s argument %s should be %s type' % (func.__name__, arg_name, arg_type.__name__)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap_args
    return wrap_func


@argtype('bar', int)
@argtype('foo', int)
def work(foo, bar):
    print 'hello word'

work(foo='a', bar=1)
```

Besides, I think use isinstance is more suitable if there is inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

[`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance) does this. It accepts the type and subtypes.

```
if not isinstance(arg,<required type>):
    raise TypeError("arg: expected `%s', got `%s'"%(<required type>,type(arg))
```

After eliminating all duplication (DRY principle), this becomes:

```
(n,t)=('arg',<required_type>);o=locals()[n]
if not isinstance(o,t):
    raise TypeError("%(n)s: expected `%(t)s', got `%(rt)s'"
            %dict(locals(),rt=type(o)) # fine in this particular case.
                                       # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/648265
                                       # for other ways and limitations
del n,t,o
```

Personally, I would use `assert` instead unless I care about which exceptions it throws (which I typically don't - an invalid argument is a fatal error, so I'm only interested in the fact one was thrown):

```
assert isinstance(arg,<type>),"expected `%s',got `%s'"%(<type>,type(arg))
        #arg name would be seen in the source in stacktrace
```

Also consider [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) instead of explicit type checks (this includes checking for special members, e.g. `__iter__` for iterables). Full "duck typing vs type checks" discussion is beyond the scope of the current topic, but it looks like explicit checks are more fit for highly-specialized and/or complex interfaces as opposed to simple and generic ones.