# Type hinting a list of specific strings in Python

Tags: python, string, union, type-hinting, literals

**I have a function as shown below:**

```
from typing import List, Literal, Union


def foo(possible_values: List[Union[Literal['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']]]):
    return {}
```

Now this is how I want the code to behave:

whenever the `possible_values` parameter gets values other than `["abcd", "efgh","ijkl"]`

Eg:

```
res = foo(possible_values=["abc", "efgh"])
```

It should throw an error as `abc` is not defined in the function signature.

However,

```
res = foo(possible_values=["abcd", "efgh"])
```

should work fine as they are subset of what is defined.

Currently, with the above code, it just accepts any arbitrary list of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make python throw errors if the type of the argument passed to the annotated function doesn't match the one specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667403/is-it-possible-to-make-python-throw-errors-if-the-type-of-the-argument-passed-to)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to constrain values to a predefined set, you might want to use [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html). Like mentioned by others, type hinting won't enforce check and error natively in python, you'll have to either implement it in your function's code, or use a library allowing annotation-based control. Here is an example.

```py
from typing import List
from enum import Enum

# Let's define your possible values as an enumeration. Note that it also inherits from 
# str, which will allow to use its members in comparisons as if they were strings
class PossibleValues(str, Enum):
    abcd = 'abcd'
    efgh = 'efgh'
    ijkl = 'ijkl'
```

Now your function. Note the type-hinting.

```py
def foo(possible_values: List[PossibleValues]):
    # We unroll the enum as a set, and check that possible_values is a subset of it
    if not set(PossibleValues).issuperset(possible_values):
        raise ValueError(f'Only {[v.value for v in PossibleValues]} are allowed.')
    # Do whatever you need to do
    return {}
```

Now when you use it:

```py
foo(['abcd', 'efgh'])
# output: {}
foo(['abc', 'efgh'])
# ValueError: Only ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'] are allowed.
```