# Argument of Enum type only Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I have a simple piece of Python code, I have a number of enums defined like this:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from enum import Enum

class BW(Enum):
    LTE1p4           = 0
    LTE3             = 1
    LTE5             = 2
    LTE10            = 3
    LTE15            = 4
    LTE20            = 5
```

I want member functions of a class to only accept this Enum type as an argument and the script should not run otherwise, here is my main class:

```
class Breithorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.RX_Settings = {}
        self.TX_Settings = {}

    def RX_BW(self,BW):
        self.RX_Settings['BW'] = BW
```

I want the member function to only accept these kind of calls:

```
Breithorn.RX_BW(BW.LTE5)
```

And reject (syntax error) these kind of calls:

```
Breithorn.RX_BW(44)
```

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: The existing answers cover the question, but if you just want a syntax warming when using it incorrectly you could look at using python3.5 and its new [type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#acceptable-type-hints) which some editors pay attention to.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make this a Syntax Error, as that is discovered in the parsing process, at which point the parser has no idea what those symbols are bound to.

You can [check the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python) at runtime in the function and raise an exception.

Python uses duck typing, to discover these kind of problems you need unit or integration tests.

Comment: Thanks you, I've tried this and it looks like its working, is this correct?     def SetRX_BW(self,bw):
        if type(bw) != BW:
            print "Must be BW.xxx format"
            return
        self.RX_Settings['BW'] = bw

Comment: @EoinOConnell, raise an exception, don't just print an error.

Answer (score 1):

`SyntaxError`s are usually discovered by Python itself, and indicate that Python doesn't know how to parse the program code.  For example:

```
if False;
```

is a `SyntaxError` because the line does not end with a colon (`:`).  While you could manually generate one like this:

```
    def RX_BW(self, BW_val):
        if not isinstance(BW_val, BW):
            raise SyntaxError('%s is not a member of %s' % (BW_val, BW))
```

That doesn't make much sense.  What you probably want is to raise a `TypeError` as the type of the passed in argument doesn't match the expectation:

```
    def RX_BW(self, BW_val):
        if not isinstance(BW_val, BW):
            raise TypeError('%s is not a member of %s' % (BW_val, BW))
        self.RX_Settings['BW'] = BW_val
```

As a side note:  notice I the changed the name of the parameter so that we could check against the `Enum`.

Comment: This highlights the issue perfectly - to raise any type of Exception, your python code must be parsed and executing already.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is use assert to check this at runtime. Python is completely dynamic typed, so you cannot throw a syntax error for stuff like that.

```
class Breithorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.RX_Settings = {}
        self.TX_Settings = {}

    def RX_BW(self,vat):
        assert isinstance(val,BW), "Breithorn.RX_BW(): input value is not of type BW"
        self.RX_Settings['BW'] = BW
```

Assert automatically throws an AssertionError if it is not fulfilled.

Comment: `assert` is disabled with the `-O` flag, and should not be used to check parameters you don't control.