# How do I check if there is a string item in a list of mixed types, in python

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a `list l1 = ['s',1,2] and l2 = [1,2,3]`.
Obviously `l1` has an item of string type and `l2` doesn't.

But when a list gets super large and I do not know the items in a list, how do I know if this list contains an item of string type.

Comment: How do the lists "grow"? If you add items yourself, you can set a flag once you add a string to the list.

Answer (score 5):

```
if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in your_list):
    print("the list contains a string")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and check if, at each index of your array, the value is corresponding to a number.
Use ascii code ( code 48 to 57 for 0 to 9)
If the ascii code of your value is between 48 and 57, you know it's a number.
If not, you know it's not a number.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this post : [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

**quote** : *"Since Python encourages Duck Typing, you should just try to use the object's methods the way you want to use them. So if your function is looking for a writable file object, don't check that it's a subclass of file, just try to use its .write() method!"*
(This answer were quite suprising to me)

The way i understood that is that you have to act like if all your items in your list were like you want (we don't know yet what do you want to do with your lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`if any(type(each_item) is str for each_item in l1):
    # Do something`

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `isinstance` function:

```
def hasString(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            return True
    return False

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ['s', 2, 3]

print(hasString(l1))  # False
print(hasString(l2))  # True
```

Comment: This is just a re-creation in a function of [rsm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39013037/4686625).

Comment: @Mitch, SO has some issues with websockets, I see no answers till I have posted mine. It's pretty frustrating