# type identification and conversion for error traping in python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error

I am writing a program to generate random numbers that then asks you to guess the number that has been generated.
However, as an extension task I have been asked to make the program work even if a letter is put in to the input so I created a while loop to check the type of date in the variable guess. But I do not know how to get it to identify the difference between letters and numbers within python.

**I need to find a way of checking a string to see if it contains only numbers and if it does I then need to convert the variable to an int so that the program can continue however if it does not contain only numbers I need it to ask for the user to input a number again**

Here is my pseudo code:

```
while type(guess) != type(int)
    if type(guess) == type (**number**):
        guess = int(guess)
    else:
        guess = input('You did not input a number try again: ')
```

I would like this to go in place of the bold code below however I need to know what to put instead of number to allow the guess to become an int so that I can escape the while loop.

here is my original code: (the code i want to replace is the first while loop as highlighted by the  *** ***

```
import random
x=random.randint(1,100)
print (x)
guess = (input('Can you guess what it is? '))
num_guess=1
***while type(guess) != type(int):
    if type(guess) == type(int):
        guess = int(guess)
    else:
        guess = input('You did not input a number try again: '***)    
while guess != x:
    if guess < x:
        print ('No, the number I am thinking of is higher than ' + str(guess))
        guess = int(input('Guess again: '))
    elif guess > x:
        print ('No, the number I am thinking of is lower than ' + str(guess))
        guess = int(input('Guess again: '))
    else:
        guess = int(input('Guess again: '))
    num_guess = num_guess +1

print ('Well done! The answer was ' + str(x) + ' and you found it in ' + str(num_guess) + ' guesses.')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this python 2.x or Python 3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: Have a look at the `isinstance` builtin, as in `isinstance(guess, int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric

here lists some methods like str.isnumeric which would help you determine what you have in your string.

as for your code, if you are using python 2 you should use raw_input instead of input. this will give you all input as a string for you to work with. you will have to cast these to a number if you want to confirm the answer.

Also worth mentioning is that when doing a type check in python you should use isinstance https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance.
This is more pythonic and stops you running into odd bugs when it comes to subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way also:

```
import random
x = random.randint(1,100)
#Current guess count
num_guess=1
#maximum guess count
max_guess_guess = 3
while 1:
    try:
        guess = int(raw_input(' Can you guess what it is? '))
        if guess == x:
            print ('Well done! The answer was ' + str(x) + ' and you found it in ' + str(num_guess) + ' guesses.')
            break  
        elif guess < x:
            print ('No, the number I am thinking of is higher than ' + str(guess))
        elif guess > x:
            print ('No, the number I am thinking of is lower than ' + str(guess))
    except Exception, e:
        pass  
    if num_guess >= max_guess_guess:
        print ('You are fail to guess! The guess guess was over please try next time.' )
        break
    num_guess+=1
```