# Python - how to test if a users input is a decimal number

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, decimal

I am writing a program that needs to check if a users input is a decimal (the users input must be a deciamal number),I was wondering how I could test a varible to see if it contains only a decimal number.

Thanks,
Jarvey

Comment: If you want to know whether or not the number you are testing has a value to the right of the decimal point, you can use modulus 1 and it the answer is not 0 it is ia decimal.

`5 % 1 == 0` and `5.25 % 1 = 0.25`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U also could use a Try/Except to check if the variable is an integer:

```
try:    
    val = int(userInput) 
except ValueError:    
    print("That's not an int!")
```

or a float:

```
try:    
    val = float(userInput) 
except ValueError:    
    print("That's not an float!")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, this one seemed to work but it also allows charaters and I want is float numbers, do you have any idea how I could stop characters begin accepted?

Comment: How do you mean? If I type in anything other than a number it raises the exception. So in this case it prints: That's not an float!

Comment: Be aware that `int(12.3)` also works fine but `12.3` is a float, not an integer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [float.is_integer()](http://float.is_integer()%20method) method.
Example:
data = float(input("Input number"))

```
if data.is_integer():
  print (str(int(data)) + ' is an integer')
else:
  print (str(data) + ' is not an integer')
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way of doing this in python but it doesn't work in a new window/file.

```
>>> variable=5.5
>>> isinstance(variable, float)
True

>>> variable=5
>>> isinstance(variable, float)
False
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(var, float):
    ...
```

Comment: when I do this it will not allow a decimal number but will allow text. what is a way that I can only allow a decimal number like '0.2' or '1.5' to be accepted but an input like 'hello' will be rejected?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by converting to int:

```
    try:
       val = int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
       print("That's not an int!")
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

(one) fast anwer

```
a=1
b=1.2
c=1.0
d="hello"

l=[a,b,c,d]

for i in l:
  if type(i) is float:
    print(i)

 #result : 1.0, 1.2
```

long answer : [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)