# How to create a condition based on data type of variable in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm programming a loop in which in each iteration the variable is either a series or an integer. I need to do different things in each case. How do I check the datatype and use it in a condition?

I've tried doing
if(type(i)==)
But it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need compare with `pd.Series`:

```
i = pd.Series([1,2])
print (type(i) == pd.Series)
True
```

---

```
i = 5
print (type(i) == int)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `isinstance(object, classinfo)` built-in function from Python defined [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument

So you can use it like this:

```
if isinstance(i, pd.Series)
```

and

```
if isinstance(i, int)
```