# Check if pandas dataframe was passed to function

Tags: python, pandas, python-typing

I have a function defined like this:

```
def demand_cleaning(df=None, location, output,_input,tables):
```

And I would like to test if `df` was passed or not (`df` is a pandas `DataFrame`)

If `df` is not passed I want to do something like

```
if df is None:
    df = pd.read_pickle(tables + "Demand Raw")
```

But this test does not work now. and I get this

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I get the feeling that ValueError isn't coming from something you've shown us.

Comment: You understand that after changing your file, you need to save it before running?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal `bool(pd.DataFrame() == None)` raises that exact same ValueError. OP should change his test to `df is None`. `df== None`  compares all `df`'s values to `None`, returning a DataFrame of booleans. The `if` then asks `bool(<this df>)`, but `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous`

Comment: I reckon he is always passing a dataframe, so what he needs to do is check `if df.empty:`

Comment: `df is None` will always return `False`

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal obviously not, or he wouldn't try to overwrite it with the contents of a file if it were `None`

Comment: I tried `bool(pd.DataFrame() == None)` and you're right about the ValueError. Neat to know.

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal if it is an optional argument to the function it can be `None`. What I do find strange is that this function signature doesn't give a `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`

Comment: It finally worked, I forgot to re import the library is working on. Many thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
def g(var):
    if isinstance(var, pd.DataFrame):
        print("good to go")
    else:
        print("Nah!")
        print(type(var))

a = None 

b = pd.DataFrame()

print(g(a))

"""
output>>> 

Nah!
<type 'NoneType'>
"""

print(g(b))

"""
output>>> 

good to go
"""
```

Comment: I try this "if ~isinstance(df,pd.DataFrame):" but got "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Yeah, you're not helping with this repeated error message, show us the full traceback - see @Jon Clements♦  comment

Comment: That's the result i have "~(isinstance(d,pd.DataFrame))
Out[62]: -2" i guess this can't go in a if. How comes ~don't give back "false"?

Answer (score 7):

You can say instead:

```
if df is None:
```

If you want to check for a dataframe contains data check:

```
if not df.empty:
```

Comment: If I try "if df is None:" but pass a dataframe i get this message
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Nicolas there's no way you'd get that `ValueError` using `is` instead of `==`...

Comment: @Nicolas You forgot to hit Ctrl+S and save your code.

Answer (score 4):

Try to perform a type check directly:

```
if isinstance(df, pandas.DataFrame):
    pass
```

Keep in mind, that the second argument of `isinstance` depends on the namespace you have pandas imported into. This usually is `pd`, which would yield to `pd.DataFrame`.
Have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python).