# Why does my loop not recognize any data values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I am learning data structures and algorithms and decided to start up a quick code for separating a list into data types. My goal is to have a loop that checks each value in a list and then have if statements to determine whether it's an int, bool, string, or float. I am not sure why, but something with the conditional statements is off because it runs my final "else" statement.

```
myList = ['test',3,True,'chicken',False,95,33/4,.02,'rabbit',False]
myInts = []
myBools = []
myStrings = []
myFloats = []

for a in myList:
  if a == int:
    myInts.append(a)
  elif a == bool:
    myBools.append(a)
  elif a == str:
    myStrings.append(a)
  else:
    myFloats.append(a)

print('Ints:', myInts)
print('Bools:',myBools)
print('Strings:',myStrings)
print('Floats:',myFloats)
```

Comment: A number will never be `int`, `bool`, `str`, `float`, or `str`. Those are types, and values are not equal to their types. Use `type(a) is int` and so on.

Comment: Rather, use `isinstance(a, bool)` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `type(x)` in order to determine the type.
But what you really want to do is use: `isinstance(a, int)`. Where you can change the second argument to be any type such as str, bool, etc.

Comment: Is it better to use isinstance(a,int) or to use type(a) == int?

Comment: You can, be the pythonic way would be using `isinstance()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shortcut way, also using `isinstance` method, to get every type in a separated list as

```
myStrings=[s for s in myList if isinstance(s,str)]
```

and do the same for the other types.