# How to check data type of variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to check the type of input, check if data is float or int.

```
# type of inData will be String
inData = input("Enter Data")

if inData.isdigit():
    print("Integer")
```

This will check if the `inData` is an integer, but this won't check for float type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this python 3 or python 2?

Comment: `//` is not how you comment in python

Comment: `inData` is of type `str`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)

Comment: python 3 -- input() method...

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to check whether inData can be converted to float.
You can do that like this:

```
def isFloat(x):
    try:
        float(x) #tries to convert x to float. raises an exception if unsuccessful
    except ValueError:
        return False # return false if exception was raised
    return True

if isFloat(inData):
    print("Float")
```

For understanding exceptions have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Please do not post answers to duplicate questions. Flag them as duplicate instead (unless someone has already voted to close as a duplicate).

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) builtin to see the type of an object.

For example, `type(inData) is float` will return True if `inData` is a `float`.

Comment: inData is already string because of input() method. if you use type(inData) method then it will return string

Comment: You want to use `isinstance(inData, float)` for what you are trying to accomplish, which is still wrong because `inData` is a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Comment: `type(X) is Y` will give you a false negative if `X` is an instance of a subtype of `Y`. Compare `type(True) is int` with `isinstance(True, int)`.

Comment: let me put it in another way. Is there any similar method similar to isdigit() method..??

Comment: Shankar: **No**, there isn't one.