# using recursive function and structure type in python?

Tags: python, json

I have one json file which i want to iterate using recursive function , but how to check whether my json structure is string , array , list or object ?

If its array and inside array there are 5 objects how to access objects using recursive function in python ?

{{ID: 1234,Custid:23456,req:{name:abc,std:2}}{ID:2789,custid:56897}} this is the json...i read it using loads in data

Comment: use `isinstance`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: can you show algorithm for that..considering i loaded my json file in variable 'data' ? @mehrdad-pedramfar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion, and use `type()` or `isinstance()` to decide what to do.

```
def handle(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        # do dict stuff
        for key, val in x.items():
            handle(val)
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        # do list stuff
        for val in x:
            handle(val)
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        # do string stuff
        print(x)
    elif isinstance(x, (int, float)):
        # maybe integer, float, etc
        print(x)
    else:
        print("None???")

d = json.loads(json_string)

handle(d)
```

Above recursive implementation will handle your use case of `array in array`, `dict in array`, etc

Comment: What is this function for?

Comment: As OP said `i want to iterate using recursive function`.

Comment: @U9-Forward it's a dummy example (using recursion and `isinstance()` checks) of what the OP asks for.

Comment: i Did it..its a list...now how to iterate over 5 objects which is present inside the list using recursive function ?

Comment: `for val in x:` above will iterate over them one by one. It will again call the recursive `handle`, which will take care of the values in that array, whatever it is.

Just try running the above code with different values of `json_string`.
Here : https://ideone.com/OvEFk8

Comment: i did it bro but i guess its not going inside object @Tushar

Comment: {{ID: 1234,Custid:23456,req:{name:abc,std:2}}{ID:2789,custid:56897}} this is the json...i read it using loads in data

Comment: The data you gave doesn't look like a valid JSON. In fact, not even a valid python dictionary/list. You have 2 dictionaries inside 1 dictionary, without keys. That should be an array.

I just updated the above example with your data, after adding quotes and replacing the outermost `{}` by `[]`, to make it a valid python structure.

https://ideone.com/OvEFk8

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance`:

```
s='this is a string (str)'
if isinstance(s,str):
    do something
```

Also able to do multiple like:

```
isinstance(s,(str,int))
```

Or more inefficient way by checking `type`:

```
if type(s) is str:
    do something
```

This is able to use multiple like:

```
type(s) in (str,int)
```

But in these solutions i recommend to use `isinstance`

Comment: as a general rule, `isinstance()` is the recommanded way unless you really want to check the _exact_ type.