# how to check if a variable is integer?

Tags: python

how can I check in a statement if a variable is an integer?

like for string, we can say:

```
if i == " "
    return something
```

how would I say:  `if i == integer`??

Comment: You should read these consistent answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
if type(i) == int:
     do_this()
```

Or like this:

```
if isinstance(i, int):
     do_this()
```

You will find more info here: [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python) (of which I think your question is a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`isinstance`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html):

```
for kee, val in valStore.items():
     if isinstance(key, int):
          writehist.writerow([key] + [val])
```