# python handling different types of inputs properly with try/except paradigm

Tags: python, function, validation, exception, input

Referencing this question: [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

It is said that the best way to check for inputs is to not check them - that is to let try/except blocks take care of bad inputs.

My question is that if I want to design a function that handles multiple inputs, my intuition is to do something like this

```py
def my_function(self, input):
    if isinstance(input, type):
        ...do this
    elif isinstance(input, type2):
        ...do that
    else
        print("can only handle type and type2")
        raise TypeError
```

but this is un-pythonic. How should I structure it?

In my specific use-case, I want to make a function that can handle a `list`or a `pandas DataFrame`, but from a function design POV, how should I design that in a try except paradigm? It kind of feels "ugly," but I also haven't seen code directly that does this in python yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look functionally too *"ugly"*, providing it adds no convoluted code and is readable.

But if you've multiple checks, you will end up adding more `if`s. If you are worried about that, a dictionary approach seems legible also:

```
def call_integer():
    print('integer')

def call_str():
    print('str')

def my_function(input):
    val = map_dict.get(type(input).__name__, None)
    if val:
        val()
    else:
        print("can only handle type and type2")
        raise TypeError       

map_dict = {'int': call_integer, 'str': call_str}
my_function('12.7')
# str
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple example using `assert` to raise an error when the input is incorrect:

```
sentence = str(input("Please input some words: "))

assert len(sentence.split(" ")) > 1, "length of string less than 2 words"
```