# Pythonic way of ensuring that input argument to a function is int/str?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically the argument that `foo()` expects should be passed as `int`, but there is a possibility that someone will pass it as `str` (which is also valid if `str` can be converted to `int`). This is what I came up with:

```
def foo(input_argument):
    func_name = 'foo'

    if type(input_argument) is not int or type(input_argument) is not str:
        print(
            '%s: "input_argument" expects int/str, not %s' % (
                func_name,
                type(input_argument)
            )
        )
        return None
    try:
        input_argument= int(input_argument)
    except:
        print(
            '%s: "input_argument" expects number in str/int format' % func_name
        )
        return None
```

Is there something that is built-in which could simplify this in a more pythonic way?

**Edit:** boolean type should be treated as invalid

Comment: Frankly I'd just simplify that to `input_argument = int(input_argument)`. That's a no-op if it's already an int, parses a string if possible, throws a ValueError if it's a string but not one that can be parsed to an int, or throws a TypeError. And you should pretty much never use bare `except:`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe maybe i should've stated that True is not a valid type of input argument also

Comment: *Why* isn't it?

Comment: Well, technically it is, but looking from a "functional" way it isn't

Comment: Why is this question tagged as python-2.7?

Answer (score 1):

You could eventually use some data validation library, like [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/), but like jonsharpe said in a comment, the common way is to let python handle the error by simply try to convert the input into an integer.

Just do:

```
def foo(input_argument):
    input_argument= int(input_argument)
    # ... your method
```

Take a look there for more on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/154156/4279120

Comment: Our custom environment for running these scripts doesn't really support duck typing, it breaks if exception occurs so we have to handle these exceptions by ourselves, but I do get the point!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to get IDE support for types (the IDE will tell you if you are passing a wrong type)... anyway nothing will prevent to pass a wrong type at runtime, so you can check it as in the following snippet and raise a `ValueError` if the received object is not the expected one:

```
def foo(input: Union[int, str]):
    if not isinstance(input, (int, str)):
        raise ValueError(f'Invalid input, expected int or str, got: "{type(input)}"')

    # ...implementation
```

Comment: The post is tagged with python 2.7; the syntax you use here is Python 3 only. Mypy and PyCharm support hints in comments, use those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things

```
import sys

def foo(input_argument):
    try:
        input_argument = int(input_argument)
    except Exception:
        print('Unexpected error occured: %s' % sys.exc_info()[1])
```

or with better error handling

```
def foo(input_argument):
    try:
        input_argument = int(input_argument)
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number, but a string')
    except TypeError:
        print('That is not a number')
```