# How to check the value of a dictionary key is string or integer

Tags: python, dictionary

```
seatList1 = {'seat1': 1, 'seat2': 2, 'seat3': 3, 'seat4': 4, 'seat5': 5, 'seat6': 6, 'seat7': 7, 'seat8': 8, 'seat9': 9, 'seat10': 10 }
```

We were asking to make a ticket selling system, there are ten seats in total. I am planning to check they are ordered or not by data types. Once user typed their details in and choose an empty seat, the value of seat they choose will become to their first name. So that, to check a seat is ordered or not, the only thing I need to do is check those value of keys are integer or string

For example: user typed his details first, and then choose seat1, after that the value of 'seat1' key will be his name, instead of

```
'seat1': 1
```

But

```
'seat1': 'Tom'
```

If the value is a String instead of a number, there's no doubt that this seat has been ordered. But I don't know how to do that. I can use "if" to solve this problem, but that is too inefficient. Is there a better way to solve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: `if isinstance(seatList1['seat1'], str):`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Comment: Do you need the values as numbers? I would suggest to have it as None then you can check if it is reserved with: `if not seatList1["seat1"]: "not reserved" else: "reserved"`

Comment: did you test how "inefficient" is it? Probably it will faster then you need.

Comment: This does not seem like an efficient method of dealing with your ticket selling system. This does look like an assignment for a class/course so my question is have you learnt how to make classes in python ?

Comment: Please share example code of what you tried, what happened and what did you expect to happen? Why would an `if` be too "inefficient"? In what context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your system using `get`

Check if seat is taken or assign it

`seatList1['seat1'] = seatList1.get('seat1', 'user_name')`