# How to check the type of the parameterized constructor arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, parameter-passing

```
def __init__(self, data=None, item=None, user=None, seed=1):
    """
    Parameterized constructor
    """
    # data for creating features
    self.data = data
    self.item = item
    self.user = user
```

Now how to check what is the type of data in self.data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: Type checking itself is unpythonic, but if you must, use `isinstance()` (_not_ `type()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
print(type(self.data))
print(type(self.item))
print(type(self.user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function to get information about variable type:

> class type(object)
>
> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.