# Find type of GTK widgets

Tags: python, gtk

I'am working on GTK in python after creating a CheckButton or Button with:

```
x = Gtk.CheckButton()
y = Gtk.Button("Config")
```

I want to check type of `x` or `y`
When use type() it returns

```
<class 'gi.repository.Gtk.CheckButton'>
```

or

```
<class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.Button'>
```

Is it possible to check It's type in another way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [idiomatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python) to check if a variable is an instance of a specific type is using `isinstance()`, e.g.:

```
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> cb = Gtk.CheckButton()
>>> if isinstance(cb, Gtk.Button):
...     print('Yes')
... 
Yes
>>> if isinstance(cb, Gtk.CheckButton):
...     print('Yes')
... 
Yes
>>> if isinstance(cb, Gtk.RadioButton):
...     print('Yes')
... else:
...     print('No')
... 
No
>>>
```