# Pythonic way to iterate through the input which can be a string, list or dict

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and have a requirement wherein I have to iterate through the elements of an input. The input can be a string, a list (mostly) or a dict. I wrote some code to check if the given input is a string or a list or a dict etc., but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

For example, I check as follows:

```
 if isinstance(vlan, list):
      for i in  vlan:
          <<do some operation here>>
 if isinstance(vlan, string):
      <<do some operation here>>
 if isinstance(vlan, dict):
      for i in vlan.keys()
         <<do some operation here>>
```

This operation I have to carry out a lot of times (although I can write a function do expand and send the elements I'm just wondering if there is any alternate to it).

Comment: What would be a good solution depends on *what* "do some operation" is for each type. Please add more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: For example, you can iterate over strings, lists, and dictionaries using the same code without checking the type at all. This is called *duck typing*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this:

> This operation i have to carry out a lot of times

I take it that your question is about how to avoid repeating this code pattern in multiple functions. The answer more or less depends on concrete use cases - and specially if the "do_some_operation_here" is the same for all three types or not.

In the first case, a simple generic wrapper around `map(func, iterable)` is the obvious simple solution:

```
def mapply(func, iterable):
    # first weed out the special case
    if isinstance(iterable, str):
       iterable = [iterable]
    return map(func, iterable)
```

But I assume your use case is a bit more complicated with slight type-specific variations in the "do_some_op" part. In this case, the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) might be a good fit:

```
import abc

class BaseMapper(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def apply(self, obj):
        if instance(obj, list):
            return self._apply_list(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, str)
            return self._apply_str(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return self._apply_dict(obj)

     @abc.abstractmethod
     def _apply_list(self, obj):
         # handle a list
     @abc.abstractmethod
     def _apply_dict(self, obj):
         # handle a dict

     @abc.abstractmethod
     def _apply_str(self, obj):
         # handle a str
```

Then you just have to subclass this and implement the abstract methods.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  if isinstance(vlan, list):
>      for i in  vlan:
>          <<do some operation here>>
>  if isinstance(vlan, dict):
>      for i in vlan.keys()
>          <<do some operation here>>
> ```

Python's dict iteration uses keys, so these are redundant and you can collapse then (and any other non-string iterable) as just:

```py
for i in vlan:
    # some operation
```

Then, assuming "do some operation here" is always the same thing and you want to apply the operation to a string if you get a string and to each item if you get a collection of strings, just wrap the string in a list beforehand:

```py
if isinstance(vlan, str):
    vlan = [vlan]
for i in vlan:
    # do some operation here
```

It's common to do this sort of special-casing / wrapping of str specifically as Python's strings are iterable but it's often desirable to treat them as atomic instead.

Answer (score -3):

Use `elif` instead of `if`:

```
 if isinstance(vlan, list):
      for i in  vlan:
          <<do some operation here>>
 elif isinstance(vlan, str):
      <<do some operation here>>
 elif isinstance(vlan, dict):
      for i in vlan.keys():
         <<do some operation here>>
```