# mypy error with union of callable and callable generator and typevar

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing

```
def decorator(
        wrapped: Union[
            Callable[[], T],
            Callable[[], Generator[T, None, None]]
        ]
) -> Callable[[], T]:
    def wrapper():
        value = wrapped()
        if inspect.isgenerator(value):
            return next(value)
        else:
            return value
    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo() -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    yield "bar"
```

The above code produces the following error in mypy

```
error: Argument 1 to "decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[], Generator[str, None, None]]"; expected "Callable[[], Generator[<nothing>, None, None]]"
```

Is this a limitation in mypy or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems a limit or bug of mypy with Unions and TypeVar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug indeed. After debugging, I've discovered that if you explicitly set `T` generic:

```
U = Union[int, float, str] # your target types here
T = TypeVar('T', U, None)
```

or

```
T = TypeVar('T', None, Any)
```

It works as expected. If I set `Any`, it has to be the second parameter, but with union or scalar types it is being tested against the first argument.

Here's a couple of related issues on their GitHub project:

- [is inferred when mimicking GADT](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8252)
- [Type variables set to `<nothing>` do not unify with more specific variables when used in a more specific context](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6895)

#### Update: some more debugging

Basically, if we write the [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) without specifying `Any`:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', Type1, Type2, Type3, ...)
```

The expected arguments will substitute T with only the first type `Type1`.

```
error: Argument 1 to "decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[], Generator[str, None, None]]"; expected "Union[Callable[[], Type1], Callable[[], Generator[Type1, None, None]]]"
```

But if you do this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', Type1, Type2, Type3, Any)
```

It will ignore everything and go to `Any` straightforwardly, without errors. Placing any amount of `Any`'s:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', Any, Any, ..., Any, Type1, Type2, Type3)
```

Will result in ignoring all the previous `Any` types, and will check against `Type1` again, just like without them at all. But, if you don't have anything in `TypeVar` definition:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
```

You receive `<nothing>` as an expected Generator's output.

#### [Replying to the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463098/mypy-error-with-union-of-callable-and-callable-generator-and-typevar/70481443?noredirect=1#comment124599402_70481443)

> Is there a way to define a typevar that essentially covers everything except `Generator`? I struggle to find a definition that allows instances of any class but not generators.

Basically, no. From [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#exceptions):

> No syntax for listing explicitly raised exceptions is proposed. Currently the only known use case for this feature is documentational, in which case the recommendation is to put this information in a docstring.

There're plenty of questions about this feature on Stack Overflow as well:

- [Python type hinting with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282268/python-type-hinting-with-exceptions)
- [Exclude type in Python typing annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854871/exclude-type-in-python-typing-annotation)
- [Type hint that excludes a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407691/type-hint-that-excludes-a-certain-type)

Even without this bug, you would still receive the same results, as by defining:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', None, Any)
```

, since your `TypeVar` definition is empty, which logically should be an equivalent to ([from docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)):

```
T = TypeVar('T')  # Can be anything
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a typevar that essentially covers everything except `Generator`? I struggle to find a definition that allows instances of any class but not generators.

Comment: No (see the update). But, even if we could, I don't see much of substance for it in your case - some generators might return generators as well.

Comment: I was thinking that if `T` could not be a Generator then there would be no longer any ambiguity