# How can I safe object's type after inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

When developing my program, I was faced with this problem, as different types of classes after inheritance.

For example:

```
class MyClass: pass

class MyClass2(MyClass): pass

A = MyClass()
B = MyClass2()
print(type(A) == type(B))
```

Result will be `False`, and that's not what I need. I tried to search some info in `typing` Python module, but I didn't really understand nature of types. What should I do for `True` result?

Comment: That's why you don't compare types by equality; try `isinstance(B, MyClass)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object *has* exactly one type, but that doesn't mean an object *is an instance of* exactly one type.

```
>>> type(A) == type(B)
False
>>> type(A)
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> type(B)
<class '__main__.MyClass2'>
```

`A` and `B` have different types, but `B` is an instance of `type(A)`

```
>>> isinstance(B, MyClass)
True
```

because `type(B)` is a subclass of `type(A)`.

```
>>> issubclass(type(B), type(A))
True
```