# How do I check if elements are integer by using type() in Python?

Tags: python

Just like the title but how do I check if a certain element is an integer and square those in list while deleting elements that aren't integer?

For example, the list is `[0, 2, 'Python', 'C++',  3]`

And this is what I tried:

```
def main():
    lst = [0, 2, 'Python', 'C++', 3]

    print("Given list: ", lst)
    newLst = [item**2 for item in lst if type(lst[item]) == int]

    print("The list which only contains square of integers: ", newLst)

main()
```

And error happens;

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should really use `isinstance` instead of `type`: `if isinstance(item, int)`

Comment: _What am I missing?_ Look at the error message, and look at the comparison you're trying to do ;) Please provide the entire error output. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is the list element, not its index. You should use `type(item)`, not `type(lst[item])`

```
newLst = [item**2 for item in lst if type(item) == int]
```

It's also preferable to use `isinstance()` because it works with subclasses.

```
newLst = [item**2 for item in lst if isinstance(item, int)]
```

Comment: Upvoted for explaining where the OP made the mistake to help them learn, also for incorporating DeepSpace's comment.

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb right now. Thank you for your answer! I am really new to Python so I don't know much but I will keep trying to become better!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are using the element `item` in order to slice a list - but indices **must** be integers. Therefore, you should change

```
newLst = [item**2 for item in lst if type(lst[item]) == int]
```

to

```
newLst = [item**2 for item in lst if type(item) == int]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) in order to test if the element is of type `int`:

```
lst = [0, 2, 'Python', 'C++', 3]
lst_num = [ x**2 for x in lst if isinstance(x, int)]
```

and the output will be:

```
print(lst_num)
[0, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `isinstance(item, int)`

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do a typecheck in Python is `isinstance(val,int)` instead of `type(val) == int` as was answered in this previous post [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)