# Python define variable with type of other variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I define the type of a variable from other variable type?

Example:
I created USER:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str  # Not sure if will be str, int or UUID
    tags: Optional[List[str]]
    name: str
```

Now, in other place, I have a function that uses User.id as parameter:

```py
def print_user_id(user_id: str):  # If I change type of User.id, I need to update this!
    pass
```

How can I say that the type of `user_id` is `type(User.id)`?

Like:

```py
def print_user_id(user_id: type(User.id)):  # But, If I change type of User.id, I DON`T NEED to update this :)
    pass
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Comment: @George I don't think that this is useful

Comment: Do you mean "not sure what this will be in the final design" or "not sure what this will be at runtime"? In both cases, I'd just create a dedicated ID class wrapping an int, str, and/or uuid.

Comment: @tobias_k "not sure what this will be in the final design" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can define a new type and use it across the code. See below

With this you can change the actual type of UserId with no impact on the rest of the code.

```
from typing import NewType, Optional, List

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)


class BaseModel:
    pass


class User(BaseModel):
    id: UserId
    tags: Optional[List[str]]
    name: str


def print_user_id(user_id: UserId):
    print(user_id)
```