# How would I read the outputs with angle brackets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

Code example:

```
>>> class Snake:
        pass
```

and then I do this

```
>>> snake = Snake()
>>> print(snake)
<__main__.Snake object at 0x7f315c573550>
```

How can I test what this returns?

```
if snake == "<__main__.Snake object at 0x7f315c573550>":
    print("it worked")
```

the if statement does not work.
how can I test what snake is equal to in an if statement?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> By default, `object` implements [`__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) by using `is`

So, `if snake == snake`, but that's a tautology.

I think what you actually want to do is [check if `snake` is a `Snake` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152580/4518341):

```
if isinstance(snake, Snake):
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` displays the string representation of the object, not the object itself. In fact, the object itself is just a bunch of bits in memory, so what should it look like? In your case, you can get the same string representation and compare.

```
str(snake) == "<__main__.Snake object at 0x7f315c573550>":
    print("it worked")
```

Since the number at the end varies each time you create a Snake object, you could use a regex to match part of it while leaving details of that hex number to chance.

```
import re
if re.match(r"<__main__\.Snake object at 0x[\da-f]+>", str(snake)):
    print("it worked")
```