# Count the elements of each datatype inside the list

Tags: python, count

Count the elements of each datatype inside the list and display it output
e.g

```
elements = [2, 3, 'Py', '10', 1, 'SQL', 5.5, True, 3, 'John', None, 7]
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `type` function? Try using `type(2)`, `type("Py")`, etc ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(type(x).__name__ for x in l)
print(dict(c))
```

Output

```
{'int': 5, 'str': 4, 'float': 1, 'bool': 1, 'NoneType': 1}
```