# Why is it that when I return int(n) where n is a float it will still return a float?

Tags: python

So I've been trying to make a program to convert float into a integer and if the input is not a float (such as a string) just return the string:

```
def convert(n):
     if n == float:
          return int(n)
     else:
          return n
```

However when I give it a float such as 1.0 it will only return 1.0 and totally not convert it.

Does anyone know what is going on here?
Any help will be accepted.

Comment: replace it with `type(n) is float`

Comment: `if isinstance(n, float):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `n == float`. That's not how you check an object's type. See [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152580/4518341) For example:

```
def convert(n):
     if isinstance(n, float):
          return int(n)
     else:
          return n
```

Answer (score 1):

Although almost all answers I see are correct, I would like to point out that your `else` statement would not be necessary if you return a result in the `if` one. What I mean is, your code could be shorter like this:

```
def convert(n):
    if isinstance(n, float):
        return int(n)
    return n
```

However, the important part as everyone mentioned is the fact that you were not correctly comparing types by doing `if n == float:`.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your if statement is never true !
try this :

```
if type(n) == float:
   return int(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's should be like:

```
def convert(n):
    if type(n) == float:
        return int(n)
    else:
        return n
```