# Finding and replacing a string in a list with np.nan

Tags: python, numpy, replace

I am new to coding and I have trouble figuring out how to replace a string in a python list.

```
# I have
a = [ 200, "NaN", 230 , 300]

# I want
a = [200, np.nan, 230, 300]
```

Find and replace the string in the list `a`.

Using python and numpy:

Is it possible to change the `"NaN"` to `np.nan` by using a for-loop?

get the error when trying to calculate with a function:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: Would you please specify the value you want to replace string with

Comment: Sorry, I have to change the find the string in the list and have to replace it with np.nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
a = [200, "NaN", 230, 300]

a = [np.nan if x == "NaN" else x for x in a]
```

Alternatively as @tomjn mentioned in the comments. If you are happy working with a numpy array instead of a list you could use

```
a = np.array(a, dtype=float)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Is that possible by not using the "NaN" and instead use the type? 
like replacing the type str with np.nan?

Comment: sure, replace `if x == "NaN"` with `if type(x) is str`. Refer to this post for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` will deal with `"NaN"` when you create an array with `dtype=float`

```py
>>> a = [200, "NaN", 230 , 300] 
>>> np.array(a, dtype=float)
array([200.,  nan, 230., 300.])
```

Presumably this is what you want in the end anyway. If you really want a list then add `tolist()`.