# Validating Type or Class of EC2 Object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I would like to validate the type or class of a boto3 client object.

```
>>> import boto3
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> type(ec2)
<class 'botocore.client.EC2'>
>>>
```

How does that translate back into something I can use for an `if` comparison? Statements like `if type(ec2) == 'botocore.client.EC2':` and `if isinstance(ec2, botocore.client.EC2):` don't work.

@gshpychka says I need to import the appropriate module first. So I need the botocore module? Still doesn't seem to be working.

```
>>> import boto3
>>> import botocore
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> type(ec2)
<class 'botocore.client.EC2'>
>>> type(ec2) == botocore.client.EC2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'botocore.client' has no attribute 'EC2'
>>> type(ec2) == botocore.client
False
>>> type(ec2) == botocore
False
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python

Comment: Hmmm... Nice detailed article! First pass didn't seem to help. All the type checking is for the standard types.

Comment: It looks like `isinstance(ec2, object)` will work, but I was hoping for a check that is a little more granular, that delves into the type of the object.

Comment: The type of the object in your example is `botocore.client.EC2`

Comment: Neither `if type(ec2) == 'botocore.client.EC2':` or `if type(ec2) == botocore.client.EC2:` are valid statements. Substituting 'is' for '==' doesn't work either.

Comment: The latter is indeed a valid statement - you just need to import the appropriate module first.

Comment: What's the underlying reason to need to query the type of this object? Maybe there's a better way to solve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is implicit EC2 class creation:
https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/client.py#L111

It seems to me that there is no pretty option here, but you can use something like this:

```
>>> print(ec2.__module__ + '.' + ec2.__class__.__name__ == "botocore.client.EC2")
True
```

or

```
>>> print(ec2.__class__.__name__ == "EC2")
True
```