# trying to delete duplicate dictionary values from the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

below is my list of dictionaries:

I'm tried to remove the duplicate values from 'r_id'. some values are in list and some are in string.

```
list_of_dict = [{'fid':200, 'r_id':['4321', '4321']}, {'fid':201, 'r_id':'5321'}]
```

expected output

```
list_of_dict = [{'fid':200, 'r_id':['4321']}, {'fid':201, 'r_id':['5321']}]
```

I've tried below piece of code but not worked

```
for item in list_of_dict:
    if type(item["record_id"]) == list:
        item["record_id"] = [set(item["record_id"])]
```

please suggest me with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in `item['r_id']` you have another type like `str` you can try this:

```
list_of_dict = [{'fid':201, 'r_id':'5321'}, {'fid':200, 'r_id':['4321', '4321']}]

for item in list_of_dict:
    if type (item['r_id']) == list:
  # if isinstance(item['r_id'],list):
        item['r_id'] = list(set(item['r_id']))
    elif type (item['r_id']) == str:
  # elif isinstance(item['r_id'],str):
         item['r_id'] = [item['r_id']]

#Shortest approach
>>> [{'fid' : item['fid'], 'r_id' : list(set(item['r_id'])) if type(item['r_id']) == list else [item['r_id']]} for item in list_of_dict]

[{'fid': 201, 'r_id': ['5321']}, {'fid': 200, 'r_id': ['4321']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
result = [{ "fid" : d["fid"] , "r_id" : list(set(d["r_id"]))  } for d in list_of_dict]
print(result)
```

Or simply:

```
for d in list_of_dict:
    d["r_id"] = list(set(d["r_id"]))

print(list_of_dict)
```

If you really need to check the type, use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
for d in list_of_dict:
    if isinstance(d["r_id"], list):
        d["r_id"] = list(set(d["r_id"]))
```

For the canonical way of checking type in Python, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there !
Though there may be other (better) solutions, your solution will also work if you change it as below:

```
for item in list_of_dict:
    if type(item["r_id"]) == list:
        item["r_id"] = list(set(item["r_id"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
for items in list_of_dict:
    temp_list = list()
    if isinstance(item["r_id"], list):
        for value in item["r_id"]:
            if value not in templist:
                temp_list.append(value)
        item["r_id"] = temp_list
```