# why does my code always display "small int" no matter which type i use?

Tags: python

```py
def check_it(probe):
    if probe is str:
        return ("a string")
    
    elif probe is int and probe > 100:
        return ("large int")
    else:
        return ("small int")
    
print(check_it("hi"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: the "is" operator is usually meant to check if item is None, It is not meant to replace == or proper type-checking

Comment: `probe is int` is true for exactly one value of `probe` - which is `int`.  Not *any* integer, the specific class `int`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check if a Python object is e.g. an integer, call `isinstance(obj, int)`.

`if probe is int` does not work as you expect it to (`is` checks object identity, not type).

Try something like this:

```py
def check_it(probe):
    if isinstance(probe, str):
        return ("a string")
    
    elif isinstance(probe, int) and probe > 100:
        return ("large int")
    else:
        return ("small int")
```

Example outputs:

```
In [4]: check_it(42)
Out[4]: 'small int'

In [5]: check_it("42")
Out[5]: 'a string'

In [6]: check_it(4200)
Out[6]: 'large int'
```

Documentation/reference

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance