# How do I select columns only if the rows are in type list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

My goal is to write a loop to iterate through a DataFrame's columns and only select if the column is type list.
My table looks like this:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | ['bb', 'cc'] | d |
| 1 | z | ['b', 'c'] | 3 |

My code looks like this, but does not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', ['bb', 'cc'], 'd'], ['z', ['b', 'c'], '3']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df_list = [col for col in df.columns if type(list) in col]
```

desired output is:

|  | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['bb', 'cc'] |
| 1 | ['b', 'c'] |

Answer (score 0):

There is not pandas way to check this. You would need to use pure python.

If you can rely on testing only the first row, this should be efficient:

```
mask = df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))

df.loc[:, mask]
```

If you need to test all cells, use `applymap` and `all` (or `any` if a single list is sufficient to select a column). Note that this might be slow on large dataframes.

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).all()

df.loc[:, mask]
```

Output:

```
          b
0  [bb, cc]
1    [b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_list = [i for i in df.columns if len(pd.DataFrame(df[i].to_list()).T) > 1]
df[df_list]
```

Output:

```
    b
0   [bb, cc]
1   [b, c]
```

if you make no list column to dataframe after to_list, we can get n X 1 dataframe.

so we can dataframe by chk len(df.T) > 1

Comment: This will fail if you have lists with a single item, or other iterables that get expanded by the DataFrame constructor

Comment: you are right. good point

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if all the rows of a specific column in your DataFrame are of the same type. Looking at column `c`, it seems like they might be of different types. In that case, do you want columns that have ALL rows as a list or columns that have ANY of its rows as a list?

In either case, you can use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter the database as follows.

To find out the columns that have a list in all rows:

```
status = (df.applymap(type).astype(str) == "<class 'list'>").all()
```

Or, to find out the columns that have a list in any of its rows:

```
status = (df.applymap(type).astype(str) == "<class 'list'>").any()
```

Afterwards you can obtain the result by:

```
target_columns = list((status.loc[status == True]).index)
df = df[target_columns]
```

Comment: This seems like [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71506817/16343464) but using the wrong way to test an object type. Relying on the string representation of the type [is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)