# Python ensure function parameter is always a string

Tags: python, string, types, casting, assertion

I'm trying to make a program with a function that only accepts strings. How can I make a python function parameter always be a string and throw an error if it's not?

I'm looking for something like:

```py
def foo(i: int): 
       return i  
foo(5) 
foo('oops')
```

Except this does not throw an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Comment: the example I used is from there all   it just doesn't give me an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very basic approach could be to check if the parameter is an instance of `str`:

```py
def f(x):
   assert isinstance(x, str), "x should be a string"
   # rest of the logic
```

If run-time checking is not required, then another way to implement this is to add type-hinting with subsequent checking using [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This would look like this:

```py
def f(x: str) -> str:
   # note: here the output is assumed to be a string also
```

Once the code with type-hints is ready, one would run it through `mypy` and inspect for any possible errors.

More advanced ways around this would include defining a specific class that incorporates the assertion (or enforces type by trying to convert the input), or using some third-party libraries: one that comes to mind is [param](https://param.holoviz.org/), but surely there are others.

Comment: is it also possible to do it in the rule that defines the function

Comment: as far as I understand, it's possible, but requires advanced syntax, so the link posted by @luk2302 is a good start.